# Google FireStore - shiftplanning or resource booking - How to query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I need to check if the resource is free during specific time. To know I need to query on following 6 field

1. startdate - greater than operator
2. enddate - less than operator
3. starttime - greater than operator
4. endtime - les than operator
5. isactive - equality operator
6. resource list - array-contains

   `db.collection(entitytype).document(entityid).collection(u'SHIFTPLAN').where("isactive","==",True).where("startdate",">=",22222222).where("enddate","<=",4444444).where("starttime",">=",333).where("endtime","<=",444).where("daysofweek","array_contains","ab").stream()`

Firestore doesnt allow to create query with range on multiple fields .
Any suggestions (As this operation requires transaction - how to make sure that resource is not double booked)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common limitation of NoSQL structures, and firestore in particular - you are sacrificing *some* performance for massive scalability.  You will have to minimize the number of records/documents fetched, but you will *still* have to do some of the filtering on the browser/client.  Using your query on startdate is *likely* the biggest % factor, then you'll just have to fetch something like:

```
db.collection(entitytype).document(entityid).collection(u'SHIFTPLAN').where("isactive","==",True).where("startdate",">=",22222222)where("daysofweek","array_contains","ab").stream()
```

and do the rest of the filters locally.